# Azure AD authentication flow doesn't work now with error:Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type

Tags: azure-active-directory

I used request below and it worked before, but today when I want to get an access token, it crashed.

[Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret):

```
Post https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded  

client_id=azure_Ad_client_id
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=sampleCredentia1s
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Error message: `AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type.`

The same for [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow):

[image]
[image]

=================================================

I do have a origin here, but I didn't set it. How can I remove it?

[image]

I don't have redirect URL in SPA platform.
[image]

===========================================

With Postman it's OK

[image]

Comment: any updating on Azure? Or it just has some maintenance recently? I'm sure both the requests worked before.

Comment: Do you have another redirect uri type (i.e. "platform") registered in your app registration? If so, it might be interferring -see for more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#localhost-exceptions

Comment: @derisen Let's see the request of client credential flow, there's no `redirect uri` required.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error *"**AADSTS9002326**: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type"* usually occurs if the application has been registered as SPA or if the **`origin`** has been added as the header while requesting the access token.

Check whether the **Azure AD Application is registered as SPA** in the Portal like below:

[image]

Check whether you have added **origin header** while generating the access token, if yes then uncheck it:

[image]

I registered an **Azure AD Application** like below:

[image]

I generated the **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

Even using **authorization code grant flow**, I am able to generate the access token successfully as below:

```json
GET 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:ClientID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sure about I set the redirect url in web platform, and I'm using api test extension for Chrome but not postman, so I didn't find a place to uncheck the `origin header`. do you know how to uncheck it?

Comment: I unchecked the origin header but it didn't work.

Comment: can you please paste the snip of Azure AD Application redirect URIs

Comment: Client credential flow doesn't have a redirect URL, and I already checked all the URLs I set in Azure AD, they all in web platform, but not in SPA platform. By the way, all the requests worked before, like you know I already post many answers in Azure ad tag, I used the requests to test before, they all worked well. but I don't know why it suddenly not worked. I didn't remember I changed them....

Comment: Could you try generating token on different platform such as postman, vs etc?

Comment: with postman it's OK, but I don't like this tool, it requires to install.

Comment: do you know how to make it work in the chrome extension?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well, it worked last week.

I think the issue might be that the extension somehow cannot avoid sending the Origin-header. Click the arrow on "COMPLETE REQUEST HEADERS" to expand it, and verify that Origin-header is indeed sent.

There is also text at the bottom:
"Note: XHR automatically adds headers like Accept, Accept-Language, Cookie, User-Agent, etc."

I think something has happened with either Chrome, or the Talend-extension itself that means it adds fields according to XHR. I assume this wasn't the case earlier...

AFAICS the extension has all the permissions needed to skip those, but still sends them.

Comment: looks like related to Talend API Tester itself... So how can I remove the `Origin-header` ?

Comment: I found setion here which mentioned I can click the value to modify the origin header, then I set it to empty or uncheck this header, but the issue still exists.

Comment: do you know how to remove the default request header? what I found is overwrite the value of default header to empty, but it will still send the request header which may cause the issue, if we can remove the request header, I think this issue is resolved.